# Convert static navigation bar to dynamic

Tags: php, dynamic, navigation, include, filepath

From the research I have done, I think it has to do something with the `include()` function linking to the nav.php file. What I am trying to accomplish is taking an older huge site with every element being static ones and converting it to have dynamic elements so that the updating is faster. The first step was the nav bar and I can't seem to get it to work.

The route to the nav bar is inputs/nav.php, and I'm trying to use `include()` to put the nav in:

```
<?php include("inputs/nav.php"); ?>
```

It works for the files at the same level as the inputs folder, but if a page is at any other level of files, it does not. Anyone got any ideas of what is going on and how to fix?

Thanks in advance!

```
<header>

  <div id="mastHead">
    <div id="fss_logo">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img src="images_folder/logos/35fss_logo4.png" alt="35 FSS" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--End FSS logo-->
    <div id="facility_title">

      <div id="rotating-item-wrapper_main">

        <a href="facebook_links.html" onClick="return popup(this, 'facebook')">
          <img id="facebook_logo6" src="images_folder/logos/facebook_circle2.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="rotating-item" />
        </a>

        <a href="http://ice.disa.mil/index.cfm?fa=site&site_id=7&dep=DoD" target="_blank">
          <img id="ice_logo2" src="images_folder/logos/ice.png" alt="ICE  Logo" class="rotating-item" />
        </a>

      </div>
      <!-- END: Rotating images images -->
    </div>
    <!--End facility_title-->
  </div>
  <!--End Mast Head-->


  <!--------------------------- NAV INCLUDE ----------------------------->


                     <?php include( "inputs/nav.php"); ?>


  <!--------------------------- NAV INCLUDE ----------------------------->

  <!-- /nav-wrap -->
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you show us some example arguments to `include` that you're using?

Comment: All I really want to do is use <?php include(iputs/nav.php); ?> to insert the nav bar. I have dont this before on smaller sites, but I cant get it to work here.

Comment: http://35fss.com/home_test - this is a test page that has the include, but is not working

Comment: 35fss.com/inputs/nav.php - and this is the nav bar

Comment: I really need to see a snippet of code. But you're most likely running into relational pathing issues. You'll need to counter-act that effect with the `..` reverse traversal operator (ie. `'../inputs/nav.php'`) when appropriate, or use absolute paths (ie. `'/var/www/35fss/inputs/nav.php'`).

Comment: I added a snippet to the post. I thought it had something to do with the path but Wasnt sure how to go about fixing that. I will go ahead and both of those.

Comment: Ive tried both of those solutions and neither seems to be working correctly... I am fairly new to PHP so this has stumped me for a while

Comment: What actually is the error?

Comment: The input function is not directing to the nav.php. THe dynamic nav bar isnt showing at all.

Comment: So you tried providing the absolute path to the `inputs/nav.php` file, and the file was still not included?

Comment: I took a second look at my absolute path to the file, and I had one section wrong. So far your solution is working, thank you!